# Multiple output from a model

Tags: machine-learning, multiclass-classification, machine-learning-model

I have dataset where input is userId and day and Output is project activity and hour, each day some users are reporting for two projects, two activities and 4 hour each and some users only report for single project and activity.

I want output $\{
\{p1,a1,h1\},
\{p2,a2,h2\}\}$
for those users who reports for more than 1 project and activity a day,, i am not getting how to do and which algorithm to apply

Any help?

Comment: I don't understand the question. For me the question currently is asking an SQL query. Could you elaborate more on what you want to achieve and where classification shall be applied?

Comment: i have dataset of 5 columns,,, in which inputs are 2 (userId and day) and 3 target variables(project,activity,hr),,, total dataset is of 8k rows,,, i want to predict project,activity and hour if userId and day is given,,,if a user reports more than one project,activity and hour day,,,i want my prediction engine to predict two projects,activity and hour for that user for the same day,,,how i can achieve that i am not getting...